# Import Json into Firebase Realtime Database every 30 minutes

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know how to import a JSON file into Firebase manually. However, I am struggling to understand how I could automate this process.

Let's say I have a Get request: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=83034a0ad18ba4efba3f7ce9946a157f&q=london&units=metric

How would I go about importing the resulting JSON into Firebase Realtime Database every 30 minutes, or even just keep it synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into the Firebase Realtime Database for automatically importing data periodically.

But you could for example use Cloud Functions to [schedule it to run a schedule function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that then reads the JSON from the API, and writes it to the database.